# Narrow function type from union of call signatures by return type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to make a type that is basically call signature overloading, but based on the return type instead of the arguments.

```js
type Callback<T> = (value: T) => void

type CallbackHandler<TResult> = (event: object, cb: Callback<TResult>) => void
type AsyncHandler<TResult> = (event: object) => Promise<TResult>

type Handler<TResult> = CallbackHandler<TResult> | AsyncHandler<TResult>

const cbHandler: Handler<number> = (e1, cb1) => {
  // this works
  cb1(1)
}
cbHandler({}, () => {})

const asyncHandler: Handler<number> = async (e2) => {
  // here e2 is implicitly typed as `any`
  // it shouldn't because the function returns Promise<number>, not void
  return 1
}
asyncHandler({}) // this should be callable with 1 argument
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.0-dev.20211028&ssl=19&ssc=60&pln=1&pc=1#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)

Is this at all possible? Or maybe this should be filed as a TS bug / feature request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that [functions with fewer parameters are assignable to functions with more parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters), and [functions returning non-`void` are assignable to functions returning `void`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#return-type-void).  These are both intentional behaviors that are useful and type safe, but they are
sometimes surprising and have frustrating consequences.

This implies that the following assignments are valid:

```
const f = (event: object) => Promise.resolve(3);
const c: CallbackHandler<number> = f; // okay
const a: AsyncHandler<number> = f; // okay
```

And thus when the compiler looks at this:

```
const asyncHandler: Handler<number> = async (e2) => { return 1 }
// we'll ignore this error until later ----> ~~
```

It sees that `asyncHandler` is assignable to both `CallbackHandler<number>` and `AsyncHandler<number>` and does not narrow it.  That means the following error is as expected:

```
asyncHandler({}) // error
```

If you want to avoid that you should probably just annotate `asyncHandler` as `AsyncHandler<number>`:

```
const asyncHandler: AsyncHandler<number> = async (e2) => { return 1 }
asyncHandler({}) // okay
```

---

Of course that doesn't clear up why there's an implicit `any` on the `e2` parameter.

If you implement a union of function types you need to accept a union of their arguments (note that this is the dual situation to when you try to *call* a union of function types and you need to pass in an *intersection* of their arguments, [support for which was implemented in TypeScript 3.3](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types)).  But instead of the compiler [contextually typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) the callback parameter as being of such a union (which would be `object | object` or just `object` in your case), the compiler just gives up on contextual typing and falls back to `any`.

And even if you change the definitions so that narrowing does happen (instead of a `void` return, put something incompatible), you still have the same error:

```
const stillAProblem: ((x: string) => number) | ((x: string, y: number) => string) =
  x => 3; // error! implicit any

stillAProblem("").toFixed(); // okay
```

This seems to be a design limitation or bug of TypeScript.

[microsoft/TypeScript#6357](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6357#issuecomment-168901978) back in 2016 just says "unions of functions don't give you contextual typing" as if it is a fact of life, which it probably was back then.  Since then, [microsoft/TypeScript#37580](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37580) ran into this and calls it a bug.  And [microsoft/TypeScript#41213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41213) also ran into this and calls it a bug.  So maybe it's a known bug.  But I don't know when or if it will be addressed.

The expedient thing for you to do, if this were your only problem, would be to annotate the `e2` callback parameter explicitly:

```
const asyncHandler: Handler<number> = async (e2: object) => { return 1 }
```

But of course that doesn't fix the original issue from above:

```
asyncHandler({}) // still an error
```

so my suggestion here is still to annotate `asyncHandler` itself as `AsyncHandler<number>` and be done with it.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4&ssl=34&ssc=60&pln=33&pc=1#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBAMzgXjgCgKYDcMRgLjjACMArDEGAShQD44AFAJzAFsBLKDAOiYyjAAbHGgDMVANyhIsOCEIBhAIaDBxJSADWACSUQAJoIxMAPBACurYsfqoEU8NHhLCAQSgBPCCF0GjpiysbFEQpYBgPAAcMOGVVdS0TABVbdCwVcwxCJJpkeiwwdn1gcKiYuLUNHT1DY2SAJX5zQRhUzBw8QhJySgAaOWJFFUrEpMaoZtbc-MLiiOi4dy8fGv8Gppa27FwCIjIKajpGFg4udYnNkvmY31rTMY3WkIqE6r86h4ungB9Fz29bmtPpNaCVHLIQMRAcZCNCApZrEwtgBGfqQ5HTOAAb2AcDgAHp8XAYAALThwADuYCYmiguIGyLQGOAAF9QFDVsY0FiWf00JisXAWVQwTJnP8Vu8mLDOfCgkiQkoJegMAAmAX0wlwEnGGJquDk9isSKCdggdgwQQeYllfRwJVwAAGeg8js1RItcCgJLAzX0EAA5PBrCAlOYuMSdYhzN4YOxIHA+DBzExoMc2JwMGYETZ+hAwPACkV6UmUxA4MjWcAlcs4dzhQSiaTyd7fYI7dY5MMlMQjJSLSSK-amABzSw7EoQJSsfiRDQxBhgKBQdi9jAAMXYAA9sfTweLa7K3BK4dn5aka94Veqjji8XjS6mK-S2XjL5K7vWaFqwJolB4SjZaQnC9ONVFcZgSCMVhCDQNAt0IWAmHYCAR0xQJERoX44IQ0DkNQ-oPEIDDjExJCULQlB6R3PI4FECRGzgYwWCYABCA1jVNc1nAgADgFgdhwMgtdWDQAAiMSqG4GAwE3LcMH0fkGJ-P8+KnGcoDnEAYjkgA5MAAElOLNC1XF43c8X3e0TyPOBTxIhVUHfa8un2SgBUTDBkyfZEhXpd86x5b8iQE1R7XLZjqVZIA)

Comment: Very useful. Thank @jcalz.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because `asyncHandler` is explicitly marked as `Handler<number>`. It's definition won't narrow it to `AsyncHandler`.

Take a look at following simple example:

```
const foo: object = {bar: 'abc'};

foo.bar; //Property 'bar' does not exist on type 'object'.
```

Here for TS foo is just an object.